# Enumerate large number of directories and move them to another directory

Tags: .net, vb.net, windows-services

I'm trying to implement a service which will move a directory to another if certain condition is satisfied, I tried this code for this:

```
Dim dirInfo As New DirectoryInfo("C:\foo")
Dim name As String
For Each dir As System.IO.DirectoryInfo In dirInfo.GetDirectories()
    name = dir.Name
    If needsToMove(name) Then
        dir.MoveTo("C:\bar\" & nombre)
    End If
Next
```

The main problem with this is that `C:\foo` may have, for example, *300000* directories (without inner folders), and it's very expensive to execute that code.

**Is there a faster way to move directories or list them?**

---

**Is there a way to list the first 1000 directories and then the next 1000 and so on?**

Any help will be very appreciated.

Comment: Are you moving them to the same drive? If yes, this operation is almost free in most cases. Exception is when file is locked, then it's basically equivalent to file copy. You feel it's expensive, should be an async call.

Comment: @Neolisk Yes it's in the same drive. I tried for 10000 empty directories and it tooked aproximately 5 minutes.

Comment: This is weird, I would expect it to be near instant, cause all it does is remap under a different folder, so relative structure stays the same - this is how it works in Windows. Haven't tried with so many folders though. Anyway, async should help you.

Comment: @Neolisk I thought the same way, but the service takes some time to move a lot of folders. For now I keep this code, but in the future I think it will need to be improved. I was thinking in divide the enumeration but I don't know if it's possible (for example enumerate the top 1000).

Comment: Are you using WCF? If yes, you can leave your code synchronous, WCF then has a way to generate a proxy with async calls and callbacks for you.

Answer (score 0):

If you notice, when you copy-paste many directories in windows, it gives you a popup with progress and cancel button. So, not even windows can do it super fast.

For your issue you need to design recursive method, which will look like this

```
public sub DirectoriesRecursively(parentDir as string, destination as string)

    '--> here, if destination don't exist, create

    '--> here do for each file in your parent dir and [if needs to move] copy them to destination 

    '--> here do for each folder in your parent dir and call 
    DirectoriesRecursively(parentDir & "\" & folderName, destination & "\" & folderName)

End Sub

' usage
DirectoriesRecursively("c:\folder1", "d:\folder111")
```

So, you calling this method recursively and all your files and folders will be moved if need. I didn't type specific code as I see that you know how to do it.

Now, you want to put Try-Catch, if file is locked, for example. You can do retry. You should use `backgroundworker`, so you can insert code for cancel, if user wants to cancel.

You have many options and possible editions here but the keyword for you - "recursive"

Comment: Does copy and then delete impacts performance? Does 'native move' copy and delete each file/directory?

Comment: You need to understand that performance based on windows performance. I believe, when file deleted, it is not much performance hit because windows just removes file from file registry and sector is marked as free. There is nothing actually done to hard drive [almost nothing]. Same with move file. Your file remains at the same space on hard drive, only metadata about this file changes. What do you mean in your second question?

Comment: My second question is that if *.NET's* `moveTo` function is the same that *cmd.exe's* `move`, I was thinking about call this command.

Comment: Most likely. Everything calls windows api in the end.

Comment: Copy paste is not the same as move to the same drive. Move should be super fast (aka instant), as it's not really doing anything.